# How to send notification to Slack? (NoneType object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, airflow, slack

I created **slack_alert_dag** contains a class **SlackAlert** to send alerts to slack:

```
def __init__(self, context_args=None):
        self.domain_config = None
        self.context_args = context_args
        #etc...

def send_to_chat(self, msg):
    connection = BaseHook.get_connection(connection_id)
    print('The connection is: ' + connection)
    if self.domain_config['chat-send-log-level'].lower() == 'info':
        self.send_to_chat(msg)
        #etc...
```

In  **run_my_dag** dag I do the following:

```
def run(ds,**kwargs):
    slack = SlackAlert(kwargs)
    dag1.send_to_chat('text_msg')
    #etc...
```

**with dag() ... I use PythonOperator() to print the logs**

1. although the connection is fine, but I do not get alerts (it works if I put the connection definition within run_my_dag but it keeps sending alerts every time the dag is parsed) that's why I take the connection definition out.
2. I get the error:

```py
if self.domain_config['chat-send-log-level'].lower() == 'info':
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I appreciate your assistance

Comment: which lib did you use for slack integration ?

Comment: You are setting config to None then trying to subscript it: self.domain_config = None

Comment: @BendikKnapstad that's because I wanted to print 'info' I have another if to handle 'error'. How should i handle this

Comment: you have to add the log level to self.domain_config if you want to check the loglevel, so try setting self.doman_config = {'chat-send-log-level': 'info'}